# I am having a problem getting a particular time slot from the data below in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a json object as shown below. But I want to get a particular time slot from it, given the appointment schedule ID, daily schedule ID, and the time slot ID. I have tried several queries and they all fail to get a particular time slot. Can someone help me?

I have tried using aggregate, findOne, find, with lots of serializing parameters like $elemMatch, $and, and the rest, none seems to be working

```
{
"status": 200,
"success": true,
"appointment_schedule": {
    "is_active": true,
    "_id": "5eb3d9091547033ad466bba6",
    "doctor_id": "5eb1d45f28d6af2430f48d91",
    "week": 17,
    "year": 2020,
    "daily_schedule": [
        {
            "_id": "5eb3d9091547033ad466bba7",
            "date": "2020-05-03T00:16:07.232Z",
            "day": "Monday",
            "time_slot": [
                {
                    "is_avaliable": true,
                    "booked_by": null,
                    "_id": "5eb3d9091547033ad466bba8",
                    "start_time": "2020-05-03T00:16:07.232Z",
                    "end_time": "2020-05-03T00:18:07.232Z",
                    "time_total_seconds": 2345,
                    "time_total_mins": 345
                },
                {
                    "is_avaliable": true,
                    "booked_by": null,
                    "_id": "5eb3d9091547033ad466bba9",
                    "start_time": "2020-05-03T00:19:07.232Z",
                    "end_time": "2020-05-03T00:21:07.232Z",
                    "time_total_seconds": 2345,
                    "time_total_mins": 345
                },
                {
                    "is_avaliable": true,
                    "booked_by": null,
                    "_id": "5eb3d9091547033ad466bbaa",
                    "start_time": "2020-05-03T00:21:07.232Z",
                    "end_time": "2020-05-03T00:23:07.232Z",
                    "time_total_seconds": 2345,
                    "time_total_mins": 345
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "5eb3d9091547033ad466bbab",
            "date": "2020-05-03T00:16:07.232Z",
            "day": "Thesday",
            "time_slot": [
                {
                    "is_avaliable": true,
                    "booked_by": null,
                    "_id": "5eb3d9091547033ad466bbac",
                    "start_time": "2020-05-03T00:16:07.232Z",
                    "end_time": "2020-05-03T00:16:07.232Z",
                    "time_total_seconds": 2345,
                    "time_total_mins": 345
                },
                {
                    "is_avaliable": true,
                    "booked_by": null,
                    "_id": "5eb3d9091547033ad466bbad",
                    "start_time": "2020-05-03T00:16:07.232Z",
                    "end_time": "2020-05-03T00:16:07.232Z",
                    "time_total_seconds": 2345,
                    "time_total_mins": 345
                },
                {
                    "is_avaliable": true,
                    "booked_by": null,
                    "_id": "5eb3d9091547033ad466bbae",
                    "start_time": "2020-05-03T00:16:07.232Z",
                    "end_time": "2020-05-03T00:16:07.232Z",
                    "time_total_seconds": 2345,
                    "time_total_mins": 345
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2020-05-07T09:46:49.578Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-05-07T09:46:49.578Z",
    "__v": 0
},
"message": "Doctor appointment set successfully"
```

}